# ¿Como crear una tabla en SQL a traves de excel usando vba?

Tags: sql, vba

como puedo crear una tabla de SQL en excel a traves de VBA? ya que mi idea es usar un boton en excel y que este me ejecute el codigo. Aqui le dejo el cogigo:

```
Sub Conexion_SQL()
Dim strcon, inst As String
Dim conexion As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set conexion = New ADODB.Connection

strcon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=clave;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usuario;Initial Catalog=base_de_dato;Data Source=servidor"
conexion.Open strcon
inst = "create table tabla_prueba(v1 int, v2 int, v3 int)"
rs.Open inst, strcon


End Sub
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927349/create-a-sql-table-from-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server se pueden crear reglas para el manejo de datos (select, insert, update, etc) y reglas para la manipulación de objetos (tablas, vista, procedimientos almacenados, etc). En sentido general estos permisos se le otorgan o se le deniegan a los usuarios que se conectan a la BBDDs, así que lo más probable es que DBSIND_RW no tenga permisos para crear tablas.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ya pude, algo asi era, escribo el codigo que me permite hacer la creacion de la tabla, y luego la configuracion que debo hacer en la base de datos:

```
Sub Conexion_SQL()
Dim strcon, instruccion As String
Dim conexion As ADODB.Connection
Set conexion = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

strcon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=1234;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DBSIND_RW;Initial Catalog=RepProd_MI;Data Source=168.172.100.1"
conexion.Open strcon
instruccion = "create table ventas(compra int, venta int, impuesto int)"

rs.Open instruccion, strcon
Set conexion = Nothing

End Sub
```

Luego en SQL sigue esta serie de comando.

En basededatos>security>logins> se presiona el boton derecho y se selecciona properties:

-Se selecciona server roles: se presiona public y sysadmin

-Se selecciona User Maps Master: se presiona db_owner y public, a su vez se presiona Master

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]