# ¿Cómo identificar una tabla que no está generada en SQL a traves de VBA/Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Resolvi el problema, dejo el codigo por si alguien en el futuro se le presenta el mismo problema, todo el problema estaba en que generalmente no se direcciona la respuesta de SQL al VBA, por ello dejo el codigo para que vean como se debe hacer

```
Sub Conexion_SQL()
Dim strcon, x1, x2, inst As String
Dim connec As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set connec = New ADODB.Connection

'Cargo los datos de la base de datos a conectar'
strcon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=contrasena;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usuario;Initial Catalog=Database;Data Source=Servidor"

'Me conecto con la base de datos'
connec.Open strcon

'Cargo la instruccion que me permitira saber si existe base de datos'
x1 = "select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'Venta'"

'declaro la instruccion que me permitira saber los resultados de SQL'
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

'Ejecuto la instruccion'
rs.Open x1, strcon

'Ejecuto el condicional. Si no esta creada la tabla, la crea'
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
x1 = "create table VENTA (variable1 int, variable2 int, variable3 int)"
rs.Close
rs.Open x1, strcon
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: En qué es esta pregunta distinta de tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/261910/21)

Comment: Fabian, tu pregunta esta cerrada porque su primera version era muy similar a una tuya, y no especificaste en que se diferenciaban. Como esta cerrada, no puede ser respondida por nadie hasta tanto no se reabra. Por favor, mira los siguientes enlaces: [tour] y [ask]. una vez que hagas eso, deja un comentario en tu pregunta, aclara especificamente tu problema (si falta algo por aclarar). Aclara porque la respuesta no te sirvio (mas alla de decir no anduvo) y de ahi vemos si la podemos reabrir para que recibas una respuesta, si la hay.

Comment: Si queres dejarme un mensaje, usa la @ y mi nombre y me llega una notificación.

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razon, lo que pasa es que la otra tenia problema al cargarse ya elimina la otra y deje esta. Necesito que la reabran porque me sale un error y quiero modificarla para que la comunidad stack overflow me ayude a resolver el problema de comunicacion

Comment: Pero ahora es la misma pregunta que antes. Hagamos una cosa. Vuelve a revisar tu pregunta, y se claro en lo que queres hacer, lo que intentaste y los errores que recibiste, asi podemos trabajar desde ahi. Tambien, aclara en la respuesta que te dieron porque no funciono. Avisame

Comment: @gbianchi ya la modifque, y cargue los errores que me aparece, por favor ayudame si sabes de algo, si es error en el codigo u otra cosa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas para saber si una tabla existe o no, la primera es para mi la más sencilla y es ejecutar directamente con ADO

```
IF OBJECT_ID('VENTAS') IS NULL CREATE TABLE VENTAS (variable1 int, variable2 int, variable3 int)
```

si lo quieres controlar desde VBA puedes generar un recordset de la forma

```
 select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'VENTAS' 
if rs.recordcount = 0 then 'se crea la tabla
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola @pfigueredo no me genera la consulta, porfa evisa la pregunta que la edite incorporando lo que me dijiste porfa